# Showing a hello world in a Rails applicatinon with D3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, d3.js

All I have in my index.html is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>

<script src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>

<script>
    d3.selectAll("body").text("hi")
</script>

</body>
```

And the structure of looks like this for D3 stuff:

[image]

But when I start rails and go to localhost3000,  Nothing is getting shown on the page. 
I am sure I am doing something stupid in there but pretty new to D3 and trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Does your Rails app look like it's working with the default homepage and all?

Comment: @summea : Yes...if I put a like paragraph tag in the body and say hi, it will show hi in the browser.

Comment: maybe the "path" to it isn't right?

Comment: but how should I give it the path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you getting javascript errors on the console?  You're using a relative path in your view.  Move the files to to the `/public/d3` folder and try:

```
<script src="/d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

In reality you should put the javascript in the `assets` folder if you're using the asset pipeline.

Use the `d3_rails` gem (get [here](https://github.com/logical42/d3_rails)) in your Gemfile:

`gem 'd3_rails'`

To use the asset pipeline add to `application.js`

`//= require d3.v3`

And the d3 javascript will automatically be included in your javascript `application.js` file.

Comment: yes Sir I have the assests folder too, could you please update your answer in a way that it uses Assests folder? Thanks.

Comment: My Assests folder is here: app/assets/

Comment: Why does d3 in a rails app by default look for assets in the public folder.

Answer (score 1):

if the question is that you cant print out the message, maybe it's because you didn't specify to append "text" in the body to contain the text itself. 
this works (note that i call the d3.js library from the web):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">     
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Width and height
        var w = 600;
        var h = 250;

        d3.selectAll("body")
            .append("text")
            .text("hi");

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```